# Como hacer una pagina web responsive y un navbar sin bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, pug

He colocado esto en la parte superior del proyecto porque quiero hacerla responsive en todas las plataformas y tambien quiero un navbar responsive. Estoy usando html,css,expressjs, javascript, no se como hacer muy bien ya que no he desarrollo plataformas sin bootstrap

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Janda Elegant Handwriting Regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Janda Elegant Handwriting Regular'), url('fonts/JandaElegantHandwriting.woff') format('woff');
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  /* Styles */
  }

  /* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
  @media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
  /* Styles */
  }

  /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
  @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
  /* Styles */
  }

  /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
  @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
  }

  /* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
  @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
  /* Styles */
  }

  /* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
  @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
  /* Styles */
  }
  /**********
  iPad 3
  **********/
  @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
  /* Styles */
  }

  @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
  /* Styles */
  }
  /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
  @media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
  /* Styles */
  }

  /* Large screens ----------- */
  @media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
  /* Styles */
  }

  /* iPhone 4 ----------- */
  @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
  /* Styles */
  }

  @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
  /* Styles */
  }

#hero {
  background: url('/images/jungle-scene-code-from-panama.png') no-repeat top center #000;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  min-height: 686px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 135px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#hero a {
  color: #439af0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #439af0;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#hero a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#hero h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 62px;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#hero h2 span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 86px;
  line-height: 133px;
  transform: translateX(-30px)
}

#home-summary {
  padding: 111px 0 150px 0;
}

#home-summary h3 {
  background: url('/images/quote-left.png') no-repeat top left;
  max-width: 770px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 42px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#home-benefits {
  background: #e3e3e3;
  padding: 120px 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 733px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#home-benefits, #made-for-me {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.langchoose{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.langchoosetitle{
  color:white;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#burger {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(/images/burger.svg);
  margin-top: -2px;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: right;
}
```

He colocado esto en la parte superior del proyecto porque quiero hacerla responsive en todas las plataformas y tambien quiero un navbar responsive. Estoy usando html,css,expressjs, javascript, no se como hacer muy bien ya que no he desarrollo plataformas sin bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Esto es un ejemplo de la parte del menu responsive como lo querés, pero también podés implementar lo siguiente para la parte del cuerpo

```js
(function($) { 
  $(function() { 
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
      $('.dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }); 
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
* {
 font-family: 'Arial', cursive;
}
.nav-bar {
  height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
}
 
.brand {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.brand a img {
 max-height: 70px;
}
.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
.nav-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
 
nav {
  float: right;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  background: #2ab1ce;
  color: #ffffff;
}
nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after,
nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}
nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
 
.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #262626;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}
 
@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
 
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
 padding-left: 25%;
  
  }
  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30%;
  }
 
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
 .brand a img {
  max-height: 60px;
  margin-top: 5px;
 }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}
#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
 
article {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Responsive Dropdown nav-bar Bar</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
</head>
 
<body>
 
  <section class="nav-bar">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="/"><img src="yourlogo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">3</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">4</a>
     <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
 
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="function.js"></script>
</body>
 
</html>
```